# Attaching Permissions to Role in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles

I used **romanbican/roles** package to manage my `roles/permissions`. Now, I have a specific role (e.g. `admin`) which has a permissions `create_user`, `edit_user`, `delete_user`. I used checkbox for this so if I `unchecked` a permission (e.g. `delete_user`), this permission will be `detached` from the `admin` role. Here's the link for the package I used, https://github.com/romanbican/roles. There's a method there called `attachRole()` or `attachPermission` and `detachRole` or `detachPermission`. Need your help guys, I'm stack for **2 days** about this, so I think it's time to ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem completely but it looks like you got an interface where permissions can be assigned to the user by using checkboxes. Here's one way to do this.

```
$admin = User::find(1);

$admin->detachAllPermissions();

$permission = $request->get('permissions');

// loop through all checked permission passed from view
// we are assuming $permissions array to be an array of slug of permissions

foreach($permissions as $permission_slug){

    //get the permission object by slug
    $permission = Bican\Roles\Models\Permission::where('slug', $permission)->get();

    //attach to admin 
    $admin->attachPermission($permission);
}
```

Here's the explanation.

1. Get the user object for which we are going to modify the permissions. In your case it's admin. I have just hardcoded it but you can change it as per your need.
2. Detach all permissions for this user
3. Loop through all the permission slugs passed from the form, get the permission object from the database and assign it to user.

Note: Please note I haven't tested this code, this is more of an algorithm for you based on the functions provided by the plugin you are using.

Plugin also have `$user->detachPermission($permission)` method which takes single permission and detaches it from the user if attached.